# New Distribution Certificate for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, certificate, distribution

I submitted a few app updates about a week ago.  Yesterday, my iOS Distribution Certificate issued by Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority expired.  Xcode organizer prompted me to renew one, and it installed, and I deleted the old one from the Keychain Access Tool.  My question is this:  will me having to replace the distribution certificate have any adverse affects on the updates I submitted with the old one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that there are two certificates: the Apple WWDR and the Distribution certificate that is actually used to sign your app.  The Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority certificate basically certifies that your other certificates are valid.

There should be no adverse effects, as it is not this certificate, but your distribution certificate that is used for signing your app.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @gambit said. Another point to look at is Apple's responsibility toward the app customers. Today i buy your $100 app and tomorrow you decide to adopt sainthood and never renew your certifcates - why should i waste money? App once installed lives on forever unless it breaks because of updates.